# Navigation.PopAsync() don't work when being used to leave the application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an One Page application "ContentPage" and i can't close the app with "PopAsync()"

I'm debugging with Samsung J6.

```
// Instantiated page
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

// Method used to close the application
private async void Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Welcome to SO, 
Please, take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SO,
Por favor, dê uma olhada em [Como faço uma boa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

PopAsync just navigates to the root page of the app, it doesn't close the app.  If you want to terminate app look here

[How to terminate a Xamarin application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257929/how-to-terminate-a-xamarin-application)